# Get image size with golang

Tags: image, go

I'm new to golang and I'm trying to get the image size of all the images listed in a directory. That's what I've done

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "image"
    _ "image/jpeg"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

const dir_to_scan string = "/home/da/to_merge"

func main() {
    files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir(dir_to_scan)
    for _, filepath := range files {

        if reader, err := os.Open(filepath.Name()); err != nil {
            defer reader.Close()
            im, _, err := image.DecodeConfig(reader)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%s: %v\n", filepath.Name(), err)
                continue
            }
            fmt.Printf("%s %d %d\n", filepath.Name(), im.Width, im.Height)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Impossible to open the file")
        }
    }
}
```

I've an error when it comes to `image.DecodeConfig`, that says `image: unknown format`
Has someone an idea about the proper way to do it?
In the docs here http://golang.org/src/pkg/image/format.go?s=2676:2730#L82 says that i should pass a `io.Reader` as argument, and that's what i'm doing.

Comment: `filepath.Name()` only yields the file name. Not its full path. This may be your problem. Try passing `filepath.Join(dir_to_scan, filepath.Name())` into `os.Open()`. If this is not the problem, you may be trying to read some weird image format it doesn't understand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

The first one is that you have inverted the test `err != nil`, so you try to decode the image **only** in the case where you have an error. It should be `err == nil`.

The second one, as said by jimt, is that you use `filepath.Name()`, which contains only the file name in `os.Open()`, this is what makes `err` to always be set, thus always entering in the `if`, and decoding a file that doesn't exists.

Here is the corrected code :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "image"
    _ "image/jpeg"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

const dir_to_scan string = "/home/da/to_merge"

func main() {
    files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir(dir_to_scan)
    for _, imgFile := range files {

        if reader, err := os.Open(filepath.Join(dir_to_scan, imgFile.Name())); err == nil {
            defer reader.Close()
            im, _, err := image.DecodeConfig(reader)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%s: %v\n", imgFile.Name(), err)
                continue
            }
            fmt.Printf("%s %d %d\n", imgFile.Name(), im.Width, im.Height)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Impossible to open the file:", err)
        }
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget to add other imports than `image/jpeg` if you have other images formats in your dir.

Comment: Argh! `err == nil` and image name instead image path, what an idiot! Thanks florent-bayle and jimt, it works now ;)

Answer (score 3):

In case if you want to get width and height of image by use image.Decode(reader) without image.DecodeConfig

```
m, _, err := image.Decode(reader)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
bounds := m.Bounds()
w := bounds.Dx()
h := bounds.Dy()

fmt.Printf("width: %d, height: %d\n", w, h)
```